# getting error while adding class to iphone project

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to add SimplePing class to my iphone project.Here is the link of the class:http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html

I am getting these 9 errors. I dont have any idea that where they are coming from:

"_CFHostGetAddressing", referenced from:
      -[SimplePing _hostResolutionDone] in SimplePing.o
  "_CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[SimplePing start] in SimplePing.o
  "_kCFStreamErrorDomainNetDB", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamErrorDomainNetDB$non_lazy_ptr in SimplePing.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamErrorDomainNetDB$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHostCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[SimplePing start] in SimplePing.o
  "_CFHostSetClient", referenced from:
      -[SimplePing start] in SimplePing.o
      -[SimplePing _stopHostResolution] in SimplePing.o
  "_kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey", referenced from:
      _kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey$non_lazy_ptr in SimplePing.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHostUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[SimplePing _stopHostResolution] in SimplePing.o
  "_kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork", referenced from:
      _kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork$non_lazy_ptr in SimplePing.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHostStartInfoResolution", referenced from:
      -[SimplePing start] in SimplePing.o

Please help !!

Comment: check if you have CFNetwork framework added to your project or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always checkmark to add files to destination folder while adding the files

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the class? Press shift-command-n and you will be prompted to create the class.

Comment: actually i am trying to use existing simple ping class created by apple.

Comment: Also, I have added this class by right clicking on class folder and add existing class. So, no problem should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you link all the framework needed for this class?
It require CoreServices.framework